# Applying chain rule to $f(x,y) = -h(x,-y)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, proof-explanation, partial-derivative

Could someone check my work? Thanks!

$$-f_x(x,y) = \frac{\partial h(x,-y)}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial h(x,-y)}{\partial (-y)}\frac{\partial (-y)}{\partial x} = h_x(x,-y),$$

$$- f_y(x,y) = \frac{\partial h(x,-y)}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial h(x,-y)}{\partial (-y)}\frac{\partial (-y)}{\partial y} = -h_{-y}(x,-y).$$

Therefore, we have $$f_x(x,y) = -h_x(x,-y) \qquad \text{and} \qquad f_y(x,y) = h_{-y}(x,-y).$$

However, some people get $$f_x(x,y) = -h_x(x,-y) \qquad \text{and} \qquad f_y(x,y) = h_{y}(x,-y).$$

Which one is correct? If the second one is correct, how do we get it?

Comment: How did you come up with that weird $\;h_{-y}\;$ ? That looks wrong...

Comment: Because $\frac{\partial h(x,-y)}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = 0$ and  $\frac{\partial h(x,-y)}{\partial (-y)}\frac{\partial (-y)}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial h(x,-y)}{\partial (-y)}(-1) = -h_{-y}(x,-y).$

Answer (score 0):

I'd say

$$-f_y(x,y)=\frac{\partial h(x,-y)}{\partial y}=h_y(x,-y)\cdot\frac{d(-y)}{dy}=-h_y(x,-y)$$

Comment: But if we write it out on the second equality, I think we have $\frac{\partial h(x,-y)}{\partial (y)} = \frac{\partial h(x,-y)}{\partial (-y)}\frac{\partial (-y)}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial h(x,-y)}{\partial (-y)}(-1) = -h_{-y}(x,-y).$

Comment: Well, I guess you could use that highly non-standard notation...yet I trhink that could cause a great deal of confusion. When we determine the variables it is not common to change them unless a specific substitution pops up...

Comment: My work is actually correct.

Comment: @user398843 Well...yes. Yet you couldn't know, could you? In fact, your question was "how do we get it?" (the other, standard, form of the answer). Well, that is shown above. BTW, many teachers could downgrade your answer as even if it is correct you **must justify**...and this was also a problem reflected in your question.